# Remembering parent ids in recursive angular template

Tags: angularjs, recursion

I have a javascript object which I recursively display in angular like a tree with this little snippet - http://jsfiddle.net/brendanowen/uXbn6/8/

I need to be able to see in a child branch of the tree, which ids the parents had. I can't use `ng-init` because it runs on the parent scope and not the include scope.

I tried doing this but got a non-working mess:

```
ol(ng-model='box.inventory', ng-init='_parents=_parents||{}')
     li(ng-repeat='item in box.inventory', ng-include='"inventory-item.html"', ng-init='_parents[item.id]=1')
```

I found this [very relevant discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1227) but none of the solutions worked for me.

Comment: two different approaches, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/xg4e6451/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/16vavu1p/1/

Comment: @Cherniv - thanks, I did manage to make it work and even learned a couple of new things about angular. The events/broadcast method is kind of weird, but running up the scope works great!